# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 227, 227, 3) for Tensor Placeholder:0, which has shape (None, 224, 224, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to run https://github.com/AndyButland/BirdRecognizerPython/tree/master image classification model here.

Above code I could run. I just changed the model.pb file.

With new model I am getting error

```
File "/Users/Desktop/poc/BirdRecognizerPython/bird_recog.py", line 60, in <module>
    predictions = sess.run(prob_tensor, {input_node: [augmented_image] })
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Documents/virtualenv_dir/ka_ai/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 972, in run
    result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Documents/virtualenv_dir/ka_ai/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1189, in _run
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 227, 227, 3) for Tensor Placeholder:0, which has shape (None, 224, 224, 3)
```

I think problem is in - https://github.com/AndyButland/BirdRecognizerPython/blob/master/bird_recog.py

So I tried to add below code to solve the problem

```
 augmented_image = np.expand_dims(augmented_image, axis=0) # Convert to float32 
 augmented_image = augmented_image.astype(np.float32)
```

But it gave error

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 1, 227, 227, 3) for Tensor Placeholder:0, which has shape (None, 224, 224, 3)
```

I am not able to figure out where exactly I nneed to change the dimention. Any suggestion appreciated

Comment: 1. remove it `np.expand_dims(augmented_image, axis=0)`.  2. input size should work but why not resize it, if that is the desired size for the model?

Comment: @Innat: Thanks for your comment.  Ealier it was not present, and it was giving error `ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 227, 227, 3) for Tensor Placeholder:0, which has shape (None, 224, 224, 3)`  . So I tried to add above lines but still it did not solve the issue. Any suggestion much appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason why you still using tensorflow 1.x? I would suggest to use tf 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

Your model expects as an input a 4 dimension tensor (presumably an image), with the following dimension: `(None, 224, 224, 3)` (`None` here is a placeholder for a dynamic value, i.e it can be whatever positive integer).

Your input is 4 dimension tensor with the following dimension: `(1, 227, 227, 3)`. There is a conflict between the expected input and your actual input.

To remedy this problem, you can resize your input to the desired dimension. One possibility is to use [Tensorflow's v1 `tf.image.resize_images` function](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_images):

```
resized_image = tf.image.resize_images(augmented_image, (224,224))
```

---

If one is facing the same issue with TensorFlow v2, the corresponding function would be [`tf.image.resize`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize)